# maintaining a variable in c# through different ASP sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, variables, global-variables

Hello I have a Session ID variable I'm passing through from on Oracle package into an asp page. What I want to do is hold on to that variable and pass it back to Oracle through a different call. I would think this should be easy but I lose the variable value.

Everything else in the solution is working perfectly. It's just a small addition.

I'm not too sure how much information is too much or too little on this question but basically I have a connection class with different methods to call different procs in Oracle. Each one is called by pressing one of two buttons on the asp page.

One method (on button click) will pass in the Session ID (along with cursor results that exist in a permanent Oracle table).

The asp page then displays the cursor results.

The second method (on button click) then calls a proc in Oracle to pass whatever exists in that table to another Table based on the Session ID.

In order to ensure the right contents are passed I need the asp page to hold on to the session id (I got this far) then pass it back to Oracle on a different call.

in the declaration we have

```
private string outSessionID;

    public string OutSessionID
    {
        get { return outSessionID; }
        set { outSessionID = value; }
    }
```

section of the connection method that sets the parameter

```
addDbParameter(ref cmd, "outSession_ID", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Output, null);

addDbParameter(ref cmd, "rc1", DbType.Object, ParameterDirection.Output, null);

 outSessionID = cmd.OutParameter<String>("outSession_ID");
```

in second method we have

```
addDbParameter(ref cmd, "inSession_ID", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, OutSessionID);
```

I'm new to ASP so any insight on why this information is lost is appreciated. I think it has something to do with a postback being a new session or something but I'm not precisely sure.

I"ll be happy to extrapolate with more code but don't want to provide anything unnecessary.

Thanks.

Just to add that in the end I added a small method that collected the sessionId in the aspx.cs then called that method after ther postback. All the troubles occurred when trying to set the value within the pre-init to page_load methods. By calling a separate method after the click events I was able to save and recall the sessionid successfully.

Thanks for the responses, they were very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that information is not security-prone, one approach is you can have a hidden field on your asp.net page. NOTE: the user can view the source of your page and see the content of the hidden field

```
<as:HiddenField runat="server" ID="MySessionID" />
```

Then after getting your sessionId you can store it

```
MySessionID.Value = outSessionID;
```

and to use it later

```
outSessionID = MySessionID.Value;
```

Here is another trick

```
public string OutSessionID
{
    get { return ViewState["outSessionID"].ToString(); }
    set { ViewState["outSessionID"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: +1 i've used the last part with the ViewState aswell. if you want more options, nstead of ViewState you could just use Session["outSessionID"].

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. The ViewState(or Session) keywords do not work within the connection class. I presume they will only work in an .aspx.cs ? I need to maintain my session or view state there? Thanks

Comment: I didn't get you. If your code is not related to the page then why are you concerned about postback? Anyway, you can have the session[] variable if you include the right reference in your assembly `System.Web`, then you can use `HttpContext.Session["xxxx"] = value`

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain it properly but I have Using System.Web in my Connection.cs, there are 3 other projects in my solution. I have a data access layer within which the connection.cs resides. it references the asppage.Aspx.cs wher I can use Session or ViewState but I don't seem to be able to use it within the actual connection class. The third project is a collection of utility classes. I'm pretty sure I'll be able to figure it out as I can pass the session id in just can't get it to stick.

Comment: Using System.Web in your data access layer is not proper. You should be able to pass the sessionID to the aspx page somehow. Your data access layer should not reference the .aspx page, it should be the reverse.

Comment: Yes, your right, and I can pass the id to the asp page itself. However, I have not yet been able to hold it (currently trying the viewstate and session suggections) and then pass it back to the other procedure on the next click. I'll probably get it. Thanks